# how can I use .gzip file as a dataset (pandas dataframe)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, gzip

I have a gzip file downloaded from kaggle and I need to use it as a dataset (pandas dataframe).

How can I use this file as a dataset (pandas dataframe)

```
import pandas as pd
import gzip
 
with gzip.open("Loan_status_2007-2020Q3.gzip") as f:
    loans = pd.read_csv(f)
```

When I did this I got an error message: "BadGzipFile: Not a gzipped file (b',i')"

Comment: Seems like `Loan_status_2007-2020Q3.gzip` is corrupted, or not a `gzip` file, or a file that was `gzipped` with an old version that's not supported with your versiob

Comment: I agree with @rafaelc! I googled the file name `Loan_status_2007-2020Q3.gzip` and found a download at kaggle [link](https://www.kaggle.com/code/sozy20/credit-risk-analysis/input?select=Loan_status_2007-2020Q3.gzip). The file was downloaded as `Loan_status_2007-2020Q3.gzip.zip` and contained a file names `Loan_status_2007-2020Q3.gzip` which turned out to be a simple csv file with faulty file description. It can be that you file just has a wrong file ending!